# How to use jquery functions in compiled npm webpack file without importing jquery into the compiled output

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack

I am using bootstrap 4 and I am compiling bootstrap into a final `theme.js` output file to consolide all my custom js and other node vendors.

But I would like to load my jQuery separately in the header via a CDN like this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script src="../dist/js/theme.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I then handle my imports in `theme.js` like this...

```js
require('bootstrap');
require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap-select');
require('slick-carousel');
require('scrollreveal');
require('lightgallery');

// document ready
(function ($) {

    // automatically show the popup
    $('#welcomePopup').modal('show');

})(jQuery);
```

This compiles fine with no errors. But I get this error in the console when running `theme.js` on my site...

[image]

I really don't want to compile jQuery into my `theme.js`. Is there a solution for this?

I've tried using [jquery-bridget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-bridget) but this didn't work. I don't think it's the right tool anyway. I could really use some friendly advice thanks.

Comment: Implicit dependencies are inherently bad, why would you not want jQuery in your bundle?

Comment: @connexo +1 it is an old build that i'm moving over npm, currently the final compiled `theme.js` min size is 400kb - huge I know, so I need to load it in the footer, but there are also some inline usages of jQuery scripts in the site. It's all a bit filthily tbh I just wondered if it is possible in this case. These days I always include it the final compiled output.